# Flutter ElevatedButton shape - rectangle

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This should be the easiest one ever.

I am coming back to flutter after years away as I am forced to update my old app.  Everything has changed!

I am trying to make an ElevatedButton that is square.   The default has slightly rounded edges that looks weird when I am making a button the width of the screen.

All I want to know is how I can make this button a square.   That's it!  No tricks!

ElevatedButton has:

```
ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape:  ???,
),
```

But I can't find any information anywhere online what my options are for shape.  Only a few examples on how to make it round or beveled or literally every other shape you can think of except for a simple rectangle :D

Comment: you need to use `RoundedRectangleBorder` as a shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

[`ElevatedButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html), [`ButtonStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html), [`BorderRadius`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderRadius-class.html)

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      //borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero, //Rectangular border
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text(
    'Submit',
  ),
),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Wouldn't a radius of 20 make it rounded?   I will try this with 0 instead and see what happens.

Comment: You don't want to it rounded corner? only rectangle? just set `0` instead of `20` then its create Rounded shape

Comment: Accepting this as solution as this was the one that got me there, actual solution if there are any more noobies out there is:     borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,

Comment: Yes this is also correct `borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,` check my updated answer